# Frobenius action on the Picard group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, etale-cohomology, positive-characteristic

I have been concerned for the better part of today with the following problem: let $X/\mathbb{F}_q$ be a geometrically connected smooth projective curve. The trinity of Frobenii on $X_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}}$ consists of

1. The absolute Frobenius $F$
2. The relative Frobenius $F_r=F_{X/\mathbb{F}_q}\times\text{id}$
3. The geometric Frobenius $F_g=\text{id}\times\text{Frob}^{-1}$

It is known that $F$ acts trivially on all étale cohomology groups of $X_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}}$; in particular, it acts trivially on $\text{Pic}(X_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}})$. Moreover, $F=F_r\circ F_g=F_g\circ F_r$, so the pullback $F_r^*:\text{Pic}(X_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}})\rightarrow\text{Pic}(X_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}})$ should be an isomorphism. This bugs me because I thought that $F_r$ was a degree $q$ map between curves! This would entail that no degree $1$ divisor is in the image of $F_r^*$. Surely there is some mistake in my argument, but I haven't managed to spot it for myself :(

Comment: I think the statement "$F$ acts trivially on all etale cohomology groups" is problematic. This only makes sense if you consider etale cohomology with coefficients in a sheaf $G$ such that $F^*G\simeq G$. This is not so eg for $G=G_m$, which is what you would need for the Picard group. On the Picard group, $F^*$ act as multiplication by $q$. This can be seen by describing line bundles by trivialising affine covers and applying the $q$-th power map to the units describing the changes of frames on overlaps.

Comment: Oh, I see how the last part of your argument describes the action of $F^*$ on the Picard group. I had read ([03SR], in Stacks Project) that $F^*G\simeq G$ as soon as $G$ is a sheaf coming from $X_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}}$ and I thought I had an argument to prove that pulling back $\mathbb{G}_{m,X}$ to $X_{\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}}$ produced $\mathbb{G}_m$ once again.. My guess then is that this must be wrong.

Comment: Sorry but I just realised that the first part of my previous comment is not correct (in the étale topology, there are such isomorphisms, as you write). I will write up an answer tomorrow (it is quite late where I am). The point is that you have to use the fppf topology to describe the pull-back map $F^*:H^1_{et}(\bar X,G_m)\to H^1_{et}(\bar X, G_m)$ (note that “et” can be replaced by “fppf” in the last formula). The etale topology is not enough if you want $F^*$ to be compatible with the usual pull-back map on Picard groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the screenshot but mathjax doesn't seem to work properly.[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer, now I see where I erred. I had started from a map of schemes $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and deduced a natural map of sheaves $f^{-1}\mathbb{G}_{m,Y}\rightarrow\mathbb{G}_{m,X}$, the composition $\text{H}^1(Y,\mathbb{G}_{m,Y})\rightarrow\text{H}^1(X,f^{-1}\mathbb{G}_{m,Y})\rightarrow\text{H}^1(X,\mathbb{G}_{m,X})$ being $f^*:\text{Pic}(Y)\rightarrow\text{Pic}(X)$. However as you clearly show we are using a different map $f^{-1}\mathbb{G}_{m,Y}\rightarrow\mathbb{G}_{m,X}$, which to wit is an isomorphism. Also nice to see how maps act out in the fppf topology :)